# Objective-Zip method not available to Swift class

Tags: swift, objectivezip

I am using [Objective-Zip](https://github.com/gianlucabertani/Objective-Zip) in a mixed Swift/Objective-C project, and I cannot get `currentFileInZipInfo()` to work.  It isn't available in autocomplete, and if I try to type it manually I get an error `Value of type 'ZipFile' has no member 'currentFileInZipInfo'`.  I've imported `ZipFile.h` into my bridging header, and other methods do appear and compile without error so I'm pretty sure it's all hooked up correctly.

Here's the code in question:

```
let zipFile = ZipFile(fileName: "myFile.zip", mode: ZipFileModeUnzip)

if let unzippedFile = zipFile, unzippedFile.numFilesInZip() == 1 {
    unzippedFile.goToFirstFileInZip()
    let info = unzippedFile.currentFileInZipInfo() // error here
}
```

Why would some of the methods be available, but not others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually figured it out on my own.  The problem was that the method returns an object from another file that I hadn't imported (`FileInZipInfo.h`), and for some reason the compiler decided that the best way to deal with that was to pretend that the method didn't exist.  Once I imported the other file, everything worked fine.

Comment: Weird... wasn't aware of that compiler behaviour as well :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let info = unzippedFile.getCurrentFileInZipInfo()
```

...or as a property:

```
let info = unzippedFile.currentFileInZipInfo
```